# Issue with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom but my routes are somehow not working. the routes are not redirected to the component. I don't have any error in the console, and I did npm install react-router-dom. I can't see what I've done wrong. You can find my code below. Any help will be welcome.

This is my App.js page

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
  
} from "react-router-dom";

import LoginButton from './components/LoginButton';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login';

function App() {
  return (
   

    <Router>
      <div>
    <div className="cover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div className="text-white">
    <h1 className="text-center fw-bold">GREEN</h1>
    <p className="lead fw-bold">CARBON FOOTPRINT CALCULATOR</p>
    <LoginButton />
    </div>
   
    </div>

   <Switch>

   <Route path="/register">
     <Register />
  </Route>

         <Route path="/login">
           <Login />
         </Route>

         <Route path="/">
           <App />
         </Route>



   </Switch>
   
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the component page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './LoginButton.css'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class LoginButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <div className="login-container">
            <Link to="/register"><button className="signup-button">SIGN UP</button></Link>
            
            <Link to='/login'><button className="login-button">LOG IN</button></Link>
        </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue? What isn't working?

Comment: the page are not redirected to the component

Comment: I think the buttons are jacking the click event. Try without the `button` elements. Can you create a running codesandbox that reproduces the issue we can live debug in?

Comment: Ah, I see, you've a recursive route rendering the `App` component for some reason. Remove the `<Route path="/"> <App /> </Route>` from the end of the `Switch`.

Comment: Make sure you have not manually installed `history` package. Let it be installed automatically by React Router. (Currently supported history version is v4).

Comment: no I haven't installed it

Comment: here is my codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-hill-7lq2s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @DrewReese I've tried to remove the button element but the issue is still there

Comment: sorry is that link works : https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-surf-o0fhr

Comment: Well, your `Home`, `Login`, and `Register` component files are empty still, but when I stub in a `div` with text the routing is working in your codesandbox. Can you add in your example components? Link to my demo https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-with-react-router-1ptt1

Comment: Here is another demo I created by forking your sandbox. And, [it works](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cray-mfmmf?file=/src/App.js). So, I guess there is no error in your code except that there maybe few incorrect imports or incorrectly defined components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you know the difference between `import {component} from component` and `import component from component`. In my example below I'm using the `import {component} from component;`.

The `React Router` works something like this:

```
<Router>
<div>    
<div className="cover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div className="text-white">
    <h1 className="text-center fw-bold">GREEN</h1>
    <p className="lead fw-bold">CARBON FOOTPRINT CALCULATOR</p>
 <LoginButton />
</div>
<Switch>
       <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
       <Route path='/register' component={Register} exact />
       <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact />
</Switch>
```

Edit:

You're using  `<Route path="/"> <App /> </Route>` which is the entry point itself in App.js. You've a syntax error in your App.js file.

Comment: What are you trying to say is the issue, and how does this resolve it? You just inverted the routes and added the `exact` prop.

Comment: You're using  `<Route path="/"> <App /> </Route>` which is the entry point itself in App.js. You've a syntax error in your App.js file.

Comment: I have changed <Route path="/"> <App /> </Route> to <Route path="/"> <Home /> </Route> but got and error saying : Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:47.

Comment: Have you created a `Home` component?

Comment: yes, now I don't have the error anymore but the router is still not working

Comment: Login and register routes are not working also?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I guess that putting `<Link>, <button>` together can make "event bubbling" problem.

To make sure this problem, How about to change `<button>` to just plain dom like `<div>`

Comment: I remove the button element but it still not working

Comment: adding the exact the route to this <Route path='/' component={Home} exact /> somehow solve it